# Convert mathematical function to SOAP and REST

Tags: function, rest, soap

I have a mathematical function that takes 3 real arguments and returns
6 real arguments. I want to let people publicly evaluate this function
on my Linux server.

I could create a webform with 3 'input type="text"' boxes, but the
purest way to do this is using SOAP and REST, given my belief that
SOAP and REST are primarily protocols to evaluate functions over the
Internet (true)?

What's the quickest path to create a SOAP and a REST server?

In other words, what converts a function into a SOAP server and a REST
server that evaluates that function?

Comment: OK, I just spent an instructive 2-3 hours in IRC learning what REST is, and my question above doesn't really make sense. Creating a new question that's less nonsensical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an HTTP Server to handle a request like the following:

```
GET /MyFunctionResult?arg1=10&arg2=20&arg3=30
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is far more fundamental to the Internet than SOAP.  REST is really a style - use HTTP.

Both require an HTTP listener to handle GET and/or POST requests.  In Java, that's a Servlet.

Neither of these choices have anything to do with your function.

The implementation of the function has nothing whatsoever to do with the way you expose it or whom you expose it to.  You can use SOAP, REST, XML over HTTP, CORBA or RMI objects, or anything else.  The function, its inputs and outputs, and its implementation are unchanged.

If you want to expose a function as a SOAP or REST service, you'll need a web server that will listen for HTTP requests, marshal them into inputs for your function to use, call the function, unmarshal the output into the response, and send it back to the client along with appropriate headers and response codes.